# How do I choose a node for Jenkins in Jenkinsfile using condition?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying go get Jenkins to choose a node from a condition.

```
timestamps {
  def triggers=""
  if (isMasterBuild()) {
    node ('node.a'){
        runMaster(triggers)
    }
  } else {
    node ('node.b'){
        runBranch(triggers)
    }
  }
...
```

But I just get an error.

```
15:13:14 Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
15:13:14 Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: dockerNode,node
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What's inside `isMasterBuild()`? You're calling code there, which needs to run on using an executor and thus must be wrapped inside a `node` closure.

Comment: maybe you can rewrite that mystery function in terms of `env.BRANCH_NAME` instead of checking the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It happened to be that I had an 'sh' command before the if statement and outside of a node block.  Once I moved that line into one of the node blocks, it started to work again.